# Autohotkey script: Works everytime only in Notepad: Copy text to clipboard, manipulate it, and paste it

Tags: autohotkey

I just downloaded AutoHotkey and modified a script I found online, but the problem is that it works consistently only in notepad. In a Windows program, such as an HTML editor or in a textarea in Firefox, it rarely works (it seems to work once only after the 2nd try).

The script functionality is really simple: Copy the selected text to the clipboard, insert the the text that I specify at the beginning of it, along with a new line, and at the end of it, a new line, and the text that I specify.

This is the original script, which also doesn't work consistently in the other programs I mentioned. What it does is similar to what I want to do above, except that it doesn't insert any new lines, and it asks for what text to insert before and after the text.

**Original Script:**

```
    #i::

    clipsaved:= ClipboardAll

    Send, ^c
    WinGetTitle, CurrentWinTitle

    InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wHich will surround the text.
    clip := Clipboard
    clip = %inputVar%%clip%%inputVar%

    Clipboard := clip

    WinActivate, %CurrentWinTitle%
    Send, ^v

    Clipboard := clipsaved

return
```

**Modified Script: The one I want to work**

```
    #+c::

    clipsaved:= ClipboardAll

    Send, ^c
    WinGetTitle, CurrentWinTitle

    ; InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wHich will surround the text.
    clip := Clipboard
    ; clip = %inputVar%%clip%%inputVar%
    clip = /*`r`n%clip%`r`n*/

    Clipboard := clip

    WinActivate, %CurrentWinTitle%
    Send, ^v

    Clipboard := clipsaved

return
```

So, what's wrong here? Also, why is it capturing something initially to the clipboard rather than Ctrl+C, and what is it doing at the end? Also, what's the purpose of it knowing where to activate (WinActivate) using the Windows Current Title (%CurrentWinTitle%).

Answer (score 2):

- In AutoHotkey sometimes there are problems when keys that trigger a script, and keys that are sent by a script, interfere, especially when modifier keys such as Shift/Ctrl/Win/Alt are involved. Quite often this type of problem, with either keyboard or mouse presses, gives even experts difficulty and requires a lot of trial and error.
- The custom ClipCopy and ClipPaste functions in the link below, try to counteract these problems as much as they can. I have used these functions in the script below, and provide the functions themselves underneath for a complete working script that should achieve your objective.

  Robust copy and paste routine (function) - Scripts and Functions - AutoHotkey Community
  https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/111817-robust-copy-and-paste-routine-function/
- Note: using the hWnd rather than the window title, to identify the window, is more reliable. Also, `clip := ClipCopy(1)` would *cut* rather than copy the text.

-

```
;==================================================

#+c::
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
clipsaved := ClipboardAll

clip := ClipCopy() ; will copy selected text via control + c
; InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wHich will surround the text.
; clip = %inputVar%%clip%%inputVar%
clip = /*`r`n%clip%`r`n*/

WinActivate, ahk_id %hWnd%
ClipPaste(clip)

Clipboard := clipsaved
return

;==============================

ClipCopy(piMode := 0)
{
    clpBackup := ClipboardAll

    Clipboard=

    if (piMode == 1)
        sCopyKey := "vk58sc02D" ; Cut
    else
        sCopyKey := "vk43sc02E" ; Copy

    SendInput, {Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Down}{%sCopyKey% Down}
    ClipWait, 0.25
    SendInput, {%sCopyKey% Up}{Ctrl Up}

    sRet := Clipboard

    Clipboard := clpBackup

    return sRet
}

;==============================

ClipPaste(ByRef psText)
{
    if (psText != "")
    {
        clpBackup := ClipboardAll

        sPasteKey := "vk56sc02F" ; Paste

        Clipboard := psText

        SendInput, {Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Ctrl Down}{%sPasteKey% Down}

        ; wait for clipboard is ready
        iStartTime := A_TickCount
        Sleep, % 100
        while (DllCall("GetOpenClipboardWindow") && (A_TickCount-iStartTime<1400)) ; timeout = 1400ms
            Sleep, % 100

        SendInput, {%sPasteKey% Up}{Ctrl Up}

        Clipboard := clpBackup
    }
}

;==================================================
```

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this?

Comment: - I use ClipWait to copy (see my example on this page) and ClipPaste to paste.
- The key point is, which Winapi function(s) to use, to check that copying/pasting has completed.
- To copy: empty the clipboard (via Clipboard := ""), the clipboard now has 0 clipboard formats, send Ctrl+C, then the built-in ClipWait repeatedly checks CountClipboardFormats or IsClipboardFormatAvailable (both Winapi).
- To paste: send Ctrl+V, then ClipPaste repeatedly checks (Winapi) GetOpenClipboardWindow.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:
(I commented most of the code to answer some of your questions.)

```
#+c::
    clipsaved:= ClipboardAll ;makes a backup of the current clipboard content and stores it in the variable "clipsaved"
    Send, {Win Up}{Shift Up}{c Up} ;release the windows key, shift and c key. otherwise things like ctrl+c might mess up
    Send, ^c ;overwrite the clipboard with the current text selection
    Sleep, 100 ; wait for 100 milliseconds to make sure the new clipbaord contents are loaded
    WinGetTitle, CurrentWinTitle

    InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wHich will surround the text.
    Clipboard = %inputVar%`r`n%Clipboard%`r`n%inputVar%
    ;Clipboard = `r`n%Clipboard%`r`n

    WinActivate, %CurrentWinTitle%
    Send, ^v
    Sleep, 100
    Clipboard := clipsaved ;restore the original clipboard contents that where saved to the "clipsaved" variable in the beginning
Return
```

The Sleeps may or may not be necessary, depending on the application and your CPU load...

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: see the script I provided in my other answer that uses the ClipCopy and ClipPaste functions, for a more robust solution. I keep this script here because it has some comments and features that may be useful for other closely-related problems.]

- Usually in AutoHotkey a script simply works or doesn't work. However with certain keyboard combinations a bit of trial and error is required to get the script to run smoothly. Two methods are shown, setting the keys to `Up` or using `KeyWait`.
- Using the hWnd rather than the window title, to identify the window, is more reliable.
- Setting the clipboard contents to empty and using the `ClipWait` command, helps to ensure that the copying delay is neither too short nor too long, unfortunately there is not a similar command to determine how long to wait for the paste to complete, this is trial and error.
- In the script below, `ClipWait` is set to 5, it will wait for a maximum of 5 seconds, and if the clipboard copying process has not completed, the clipboard's original contents will be restored.
- 

```
#+c::
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
clipsaved := ClipboardAll

Clipboard := ""

;method 1
Send, {Win Up}{Shift Up}{c Up}

;method 2
;KeyWait, Shift
;KeyWait, LWin
;KeyWait, RWin

Send, ^c
ClipWait, 5
if ErrorLevel
{
    Clipboard := clipsaved
    clipsaved := ""
    return
}

; InputBox, inputVar, Input character, Input character wHich will surround the text.
clip := Clipboard
; clip := inputVar clip inputVar
clip := "/*`r`n" clip "`r`n*/"

Clipboard := clip

WinActivate, % "ahk_id " hWnd
Send, ^v
Sleep, 3000

Clipboard := clipsaved

return
```